# Getting coordinates of user clicked point in current MXD with ArcPy

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I would like to know if it is possible to get the coordinates from a user clicked point in the current map document - arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Answer (score 4):

There is an Esri [How To: Capture map coordinates with a mouse click using Python](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40730) with code.  This also mentions that:

> "Prior to ArcGIS 10.1, Python could not be used to interact with the
>   ArcGIS interface."

I have tried that code but I have not been able to get the button I have the code behind to activate so I cannot yet confirm that the code works.  I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 SP1.

My code for your reference is:

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class ClickForXYCoordinates(object):
    """Implementation for MyPythonAddIn_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE"
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        message = "Your mouse clicked:" + str(x) + ", " + str(y)
        pythonaddins.MessageBox(message, "My Coordinates")
```