# What is the preferable value for setting tolerance for selecting a feature

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, arcgis-10.1, distance

I know it's really a basic question. But I am really confused about this. For selecting a point feature by mouse click, we need to set a tolerance value to create the envelope. And here is the problem lies. in some feature classes points are really so close, for some feature classes, map unit is in feet and for some it is in meter. And the tolerance should vary for these case. For searching feature I personally use `IFeatureClass.Search` method.

Does there any better option to search a feature from a feature layer? Or does there any way to pick a preferable tolerance?

Comment: Related: [How to buffer a point in a Python Add-In by ArcMap's selection tolerance?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/49721/753)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArcMap has a default [selection tolerance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000036000000) of 3 pixels. The [`IMxDocument`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v0000010w000000) interface exposes this value in two ways:

- [`SearchTolerance`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/000v/000v00000122000000.htm): The global search tolerance in geographic units for selection. The application's search tolerance is measured and set using pixel units.  This property automatically converts the size of the pixels to map units.
- [`SearchTolerancePixels`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/SearchTolerancePixels_Property/000v00000123000000/): This property controls the application's search tolerance.  The search tolerance is measured in pixel units.