# Selecting feature interactively (mouse click) in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am trying to create a model using ArcGIS ModelBuilder.

The model intends to display the attribute of the selected feature. I intend to select the feature using the 'select by location' option. However, I need to specify the input feature interactively (mouse click).

Can anyone guide which option/tool can help me select features interactively in ArcGIS?

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried?

Comment: Select it before running the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a tool that interacts with your map, you will need to create an add-in for ArcMap. [Python add-ins](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/what-is-a-python-add-in.htm) are probably the easiest if you're not a developer. Your add-in should contain a [tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/tool-class.htm) that will use a mouse event (click, move, draw, etc) as input. If you don't have any experience with Python and want something quickly operating, I think using a layer from the TOC as input parameter, and selecting your features in this layer like you would normally do, before running the tool (as suggested by @Midalvo), is the best option.

Comment: The Python AddIn method I used a couple of years ago to do this is at https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/49721/115

Answer (score 2):

To do this you would use a [feature set](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-feature-set-and-record-set.htm):

> Feature sets allow features to be entered interactively and
>   immediately used as input to a model or script. This interactive data
>   entry is done through a process similar to editing features inside
>   ArcMap. Similarly, record sets allow tabular or attribute information
>   to be entered interactively and immediately used as input.
>
> Any tool that uses a feature class or table as input also accepts a
>   feature or record set. This means that for any of these tools, the
>   input can be entered interactively by building a simple model around
>   the tool and changing the input data type from feature class or table
>   to feature set or record set.

Once you have a feature set it should be possible to feed it into MakeFeatureLayer and then SelectLayerByLocation.

Comment: I think feature sets allow only drawing new features, not selecting existing features.

Comment: @GISGe "Any tool that uses a feature class or table as input also accepts a feature or record set."

Comment: Yes. It means that the digitized features are the equivalent of a feature class. As the [help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/using-the-interactive-feature-and-record-input-con.htm) says, feature sets can only be used to draw features, OR to point to an existing layer (if features in this layer are already selected, the selection will be used, but you can't select interactively).

Comment: @GISGe I'm reading that differently to you and have not tested it recently to be certain. The methods in your answer and Midavalo's comment are ones that I would be more comfortable with but I think this one is worth testing.

Comment: Well I've tested feature sets in the past, that's why I can say it won't work

Comment: I've tested them in the past too, and I thought successfully. I'm not seeing wording in the documentation you cited that says it would not work, and by my reading it seems to say that it should be possible to use feature set to digitize point, use that like feature class to make feature layer and use that layer in SelectLayerByLocation.