# Calculate Field using Esri Python Addin

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy, arcmap, python-addin

I am trying to select a polygon then it must automatically change (calculate) the status to "C". The tool seems to work in the background but nothing actually happens (the status is not updated). I have used the code from [Select and copy features in ArcMap using Python add-in tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49713) but nothing actually gets selected. If I have a feature in the layer selected already it does deselect it though.

Below is the code that i am using. Is there something that I have gotten wrong?

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

def getSearchDistanceInches(scale, selection_tolerance=3):
    """Returns the map distance in inches that corresponds to the input selection
    tolerance in pixels (default 3) at the specified map scale."""
    return scale * selection_tolerance / 96.0 # DPI used by ArcMap when reporting scale

class tlStatToC(object):
    """Implementation for PythonAddin_addin.tlMapCoods (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE" # Can set to "Line", "Circle" or "Rectangle" for interactive shape drawing and to activate the onLine/Polygon/Circle event sinks.
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        pointGeom = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(x, y), mxd.activeDataFrame.spatialReference)
        searchdistance = getSearchDistanceInches(mxd.activeDataFrame.scale)
        lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0] # assumes you want to select features from 1st layer in TOC
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr, "INTERSECT", pointGeom)
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(lyr,"STATUS","C")
```

Answer (score 2):

You left off the search distance argument to `SelectLayerByLocation`. This is important -- for some reason, without it, a `PointGeometry` object will never intersect anything, at least in my limited testing.

Change:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr, "INTERSECT", pointGeom)
```

To:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr, "INTERSECT", pointGeom, "%d INCHES" % searchdistance)
```