# Selection box from Python Add-in?

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I would like to create a button using Python Add-ins that allows the user to select a point on the map then immediately bring up a user prompt checkbox that was created in a separate toolbox. I thought what I wrote would work, but when I click on any point on the map, nothing happens. Is there something wrong with the way my script was written?

This is it:

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

arcpy.env.workspace = "E:/GIS/File_Organization/Data/Points/Points.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

class SelectWithinARadius(object):
    """Implementation for Button_from_Point_addin.SelectWithinARadius (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE"
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift): 
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") #designate map document
        pointGeom = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(x, y), mxd.activeDataFrame.spatialReference) #create point from lat/long
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(pointGeom, "point_lyr") #make feature layer from point
        pythonaddins.GPToolDialog(r'E:\GIS\File_Organization\Data\Checkbox_Toolbox\Checkbox.tbx', 'Feature_Selection') #add selection toolbox for user input

    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

If not, was I not installing it correctly? I can also provide the code for the toolbox that I am trying to link through the GPToolDialog if that would help as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have had to do this in the past and I think the key to it came from a number of Q&As here including:

- [Calculate Field using Esri Python Addin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58702/calculate-field-using-esri-python-addin)
- [Select and copy features in ArcMap using Python add-in tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49713/select-and-copy-features-in-arcmap-using-python-add-in-tool)

My code that resulted was:

```
import arcpy,pythonaddins

def getSearchDistanceInches(scale, selection_tolerance=4):
    """Returns the map distance in inches that corresponds to the input selection
    tolerance in pixels (default 3) at the specified map scale."""
    return scale * selection_tolerance / 96.0 # DPI used by ArcMap when reporting scale

class SelectFeature(object):
    """Implementation for SelectAsset.tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.cursor = 3
        self.shape = "NONE" # Can set to "Line", "Circle" or "Rectangle" for interactive shape drawing and to activate the onLine/Polygon/Circle event sinks.
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        pointGeom = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(x, y), mxd.activeDataFrame.spatialReference)
        searchdistance = getSearchDistanceInches(mxd.activeDataFrame.scale)
        lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"your_layer_name")[0]
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr, "INTERSECT", pointGeom, "{0} INCHES".format(searchdistance))
        result = arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr)
        count = int(result.getOutput(0))
        print "Found {0} features".format(count)
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I will try this out. Does the search distance only work in inches though because of the spatial reference? I would like to be able to buffer the points in miles if that is possible.